# Node.js: how to 'inherit' from abstract class?

Tags: node.js, oop

I'm building a web app with node.js (+ angular, etc.).
The app will have to retrive some data (something like a catalog items list) from different providers, who expose their data in different ways.

In that module, I will have some function common to all providers, and some function unique to any of them.

My current (poor) implementation is something like this:

```
var providers = [
  {  name: 'Apple', /* ... */ },
  {  name: 'Samsung', /* ... */ },
  {  name: 'Google', /* ... */ },
];

exports.syncCatalogues = function(search, callback) {
  var allItems = [];
  for (var p = 0; p < providers.length; p++) {
    exports.getCatalog(providers[p], function(err, catalog) {
      if (err) {
        return callback(err);
      }
      exports.getItems(providers[p], catalog, function(err, items) {
        if (err) {
          return callback(err);
        }
        allItems = allItems.concat(items);
        callback(null);
      });
    });
  }
};
```

And my getCatalog() and getItems() implementation are as ugly as this:

```
exports.getCatalog(provider, callback) {
  if (provider.name === 'Apple') {
    // code for Apple provider ...
  }
  // and so on ...
};


exports.getItems(provider, callback) {
  if (provider.name === 'Apple') {
    // code for Apple catalog ...
  }
  // and so on ...
};
```

I know with ES5 (I'm stuck to it) abstract classes are not easy to implement, but I'm sure there is a better way (code more readable, maintainable, testable) than this... :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to implement the inheritance in JavaScript.
Here is one, which I think the simplest, since you just operate with plain objects and use prototypal inheritance.

Instead of the base class you have a prototype object where you can place the common code. 
Then you create an object based on the prototype and add specific code to it.

```js
var providerPrototype = {
  name: 'Prototype',
  alertName: function() {  // this is common function, all objects
    alert(this.name);      // will have it
  }
};

var appleProvider = Object.create(providerPrototype);
appleProvider.name = 'Apple';
// this is a specific function for 'Apple'
appleProvider.getCatalog = function(callback) {
  return callback(null, ['iPhone', 'Mac Mini']);
}
appleProvider.alertName = function() {
   // call 'base' method
   providerPrototype.alertName.call(this);
   alert('All rights reserved.');
}

var samsungProvider = Object.create(providerPrototype);
samsungProvider.name = 'Samsung';
// this is a specific function for 'Samsung'
samsungProvider.getCatalog = function(callback) {
  return callback(null, ['Galaxy S3', 'Galaxy S4']);
}

var providers = [
  appleProvider, samsungProvider
];

var syncCatalogues = function(search, callback) {
  var allItems = [];
  for (var p = 0; p < providers.length; p++) {
    var aProvider = providers[p];
    aProvider.getCatalog(function(err, catalog) {
      if (err) {
        return callback(err);
      }
      aProvider.alertName(); // call the base method
      alert(catalog);
    });
  }
};

syncCatalogues();
```

Check also [Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) in Mozilla javascript documentation.

And here is [an example of splitting classes over node.js modules](https://github.com/serebrov/so-questions/tree/master/js-inheritance/prototypes-node).

Comment: This is quite perfect, I'll use this approach in my code. Just one remark, before accepting: since the question was about node.js, could you refactor a bit this code to be divided in different modules, one per class (and in different files, say "provider.js", "providerApple.js", "providerSamsung.js", ...) ?

Comment: @MarcoS actually you just need to copy over the code into different files and assign the object to `module.exports`. I updated my answer with a link to the example on github. Also updated `appleProvider` with example how to call the "base" method.

Comment: perfect ... I mean, per-fe-ct.

Answer (score 4):

I'm new in nodeJS but I think my code below is possible only after ES6. I hope to help newbies like me. Follows:

```
class BaseClass {
    constructor(){
        console.log('Object created INHERITED');
    }

    toCallFromChild(){
        console.log('Called by child');
        this.toOverride();
    }

    toOverride(){} //to override
}

class childClass extends BaseClass{
    toOverride(){
        console.log ('Override by child');
    }
}

var instance = new childClass();
instance.toCallFromChild();
```

Answer (score 2):

My response is a possible alternative solution.

I personnally do not like the native javascript object mecanics. So i generaly use a library like Mootools for making clean objects.

Example from Mootools documentation :

```
var Animal = new Class({
    initialize: function(age){
        this.age = age;
    }
});
var Cat = new Class({
    Extends: Animal,
    initialize: function(name, age){
        this.parent(age); // calls initalize method of Animal class
        this.name = name;
    }
});
var myCat = new Cat('Micia', 20);
alert(myCat.name); // alerts 'Micia'.
alert(myCat.age); // alerts 20.
```

Se the online doc on : http://mootools.net/

Comment: You did center what I was expecting: a possible alternative solution. Thanks, I'll test `mootools`, though I'd prefer to avoid too many abstractions in my code...

Comment: I am glad that helps you. If you are not waiting another answers i let you accept mine ;)